# How can I display the image clicked on another div in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to display a clicked image from a list of images to a large div which shows the clicked image.

I am getting the source of image while clicking but i don't know how to pass it to another images src.

(this.IMG1 = IMG1)}
          />
          
          
          
            
              Prv
            
            Nxt

Comment: In the render method we can use the below format to display the image <img src={src1}/>

Comment: so how to store that src1 and pass to it?

Comment: If that is coming from another component  You can pass it through the props

Comment: In my case both are in same component

Comment: If you are using ES6 Class , you can create a variable to store the result . and use it <img src = {this.src1}/>

Comment: Ok.I agreed but how to take the src on clicking the image?

Comment: Use the onClick event on the Image and handle it to save the src inside the method

Comment: Ok thanks i got the expected result:-)